# Save psql output to a local file over ssh?

Tags: ssh, psql

I connect to a sever over ssh and run

```
psql
```

I want to make a database extraction from the server but I can't save files on the remote because I don't have write-permission. How can I save it locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than

```
ssh myhost psql
```

use an ssh tunnel to connect a local `psql` to the remote PostgreSQL, so you can `\copy` files locally, e.g.

```
ssh -L 5599:localhost:5432 myhost
```

then while that session is open, in a *separate, local* terminal session:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5599
```

to connect over the ssh tunnel. This will only work if the remote system allows tcp/ip connections from localhost (127.0.0.1 / ::1). It doesn't have to allow tcp/ip PostgreSQL connections from remote nodes.

---

Alternately, you can:

```
ssh myhost psql -c '"copy mytable to stdout"' > local_file.csv
```

to stream stdout over ssh to a local file.

Note the two layers of quoting, because the local shell consumes the first layer and the remote shell consumes the second layer.

---

Generally the best solution is to enable PostgreSQL to listen on external public ports, with SSL set up, and use `hostssl` entries in `pg_hba.conf` to allow yourself to connect directly over TCP/IP using `psql` with SSL. Then you'd just:

```
psql -h myhost
```

Comment: I don't have psql installed on my local machine so the first option doesn't work for me. For the second option, I tried $ ssh knolgren@host.net psql -c "SELECT  display_product.internal_name,   display_product.primary_image_id FROM products.disp
lay_product WHERE  display_product.primary_image_id IS NOT NULL;" > /test.csv but got a bunch of errors, cold not chdir tohome directory, and psql: warning extra command-line argument "FROM" ignored

Comment: Yes, you'll need an extra layer of quoting. Added in edit. As for the first option: it's free, just install the PostgreSQL client tools